# MS Access: How does my Insert Into Statement has to look like if i want to insert only the record i changed/modified into a new table?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a continues form where the user can edit data, stored in the table, directly. 
Before the user can close the form or edit a different record he is asked if he wants to save his changes.
I use the Before Update Event for that:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
'Msg Box Nachricht bestimmen.
    strMsg = "M?chten Sie die ?nderungen speichern?" & Chr(10)
    strMsg = strMsg & "Dr?cken Sie Ja um zu speichern oder Nein um die ?nderungen zu verwerfen."

    'Msg Box anzeigen.
    iResponse = MsgBox(strMsg, vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Speichern?")

    'Nutzer Antwort pruefen
    If iResponse = vbNo Then

        'Aenderungen verwerfen.
         Me.Undo
        'Update abbrechen.
         Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

When the form loads i get the current value  of the text field by using this:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
TempVars("Status") = txtStatus.Value
End Sub
```

Now if the User changes this text field the record (with the old value for txtStatus) should be saved in a new table. 
This code WITHOUT the "Where"-Part copies all the records in my table, into the new table:

```
Dim Status As String
Dim Counter As Integer
Counter = 0

If txtStatus.Value <> TempVars("getStatus") Then
Status = txtStatus.Value
Counter = Counter + 1
End If

Dim sql As String
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Set dbs = CurrentDb()

    sql = "Insert into tblStatusFahrzeugeHistory (F_ID, Status, seit, bis, von, an, Bemerkung, Datenbank_Nutzer, Eintrag_erstellt_am, Eintrag_erstellt_um)" & _
"Select tblStatusFahrzeuge.F_ID, tblStatusFahrzeuge.Status, tblStatusFahrzeuge.seit, tblStatusFahrzeuge.bis, tblStatusFahrzeuge.von, tblStatusFahrzeuge.an, tblStatusFahrzeuge.Bemerkung, tblStatusFahrzeuge.Datenbank_Nutzer, tblStatusFahrzeuge.Eintrag_erstellt_am, tblStatusFahrzeuge.Eintrag_erstellt_um " & _
"From tblStatusFahrzeuge Where txtStatus.Value = Status "

dbs.Execute sql, dbFailOnError
dbs.Close
Set dbs = Nothing
    End If
```

WITH the "Where"-Part i attempted to insert only the record i changed on the form into the new table but the code does'nt work. I get this error code: runtime error'3061' 1 parameters were expected, but too few parameters were passed.Does someone know what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The query engine cannot "see" txtStatus.Value. You will either have to add parameters to your query, or concatenate in the value of the text box into the query text:-

```
    sql = "Insert into tblStatusFahrzeugeHistory (F_ID, Status, seit, bis, von, an, Bemerkung, Datenbank_Nutzer, Eintrag_erstellt_am, Eintrag_erstellt_um)" & _
"Select tblStatusFahrzeuge.F_ID, tblStatusFahrzeuge.Status, tblStatusFahrzeuge.seit, tblStatusFahrzeuge.bis, tblStatusFahrzeuge.von, tblStatusFahrzeuge.an, tblStatusFahrzeuge.Bemerkung, tblStatusFahrzeuge.Datenbank_Nutzer, tblStatusFahrzeuge.Eintrag_erstellt_am, tblStatusFahrzeuge.Eintrag_erstellt_um " & _
"From tblStatusFahrzeuge Where '" & txtStatus.Value & "' = Status "
```

Comment: I changed it the way you did, but now i get this error: '3464'  Data type conflict in criteria expression.

Comment: What data type is your Status column? (The table column, not the variable) If it is numeric, then just get rid of the single quote marks: ... Where " & txtStatus.Value & " = Status "

Comment: Status is a integer in the table. I removed the  single quote marks. and now the code works! The only problem now is that all the records in the table that have the status of the number 1 for exapmle are copied to the new table not just the one i changed the status on.

Comment: Also, do i even need the counter variable? I dont think it serves a purpose.

Comment: No, the counter variable doesn't appear to be used anywhere. Not quite sure that your code snippet is achieving what you want. If you are looking to preserve the old status of the row in a history table, then you will probably need to put code in the before update event of your form, and insert the old values to the history table before updating the row in your main table. Suggest you Google for something like "MS access keep changed rows in history table"

Comment: Yes, i am looking to preserve the old status. And yes i am using the code in the Before Update Event of my from. And when i remove the "where"-part completely it will save the old Status of the record in the history table (and of course all the other records in the table). But WITH the "where"-part as it is now it saves the new Status value AND all the records in the table that have the same Status. This is very Strange to me. By the way thanks a lot for your help so far!

Comment: Suggest you change your SQL statement to insert values, and obtain them from each control's .OldValue property - just build up the insert statement with hard-coded values like the above, and run the insert. If you are running this in the before update event there will only be a single row to insert...

Comment: Im not sure i fully understand what you mean with, building up the insert statement with hard-coded values. Sorry i am a bloody beginner. Could you post a small insert, using my insert example please?

Comment: Something like sqltext = "insert into table (col_a, col_b, col_c) values (" & me.txt_a.oldvalue & ", " & "'" & me.txt_b.oldvalue & "' & ", " & me.txt_c.oldvalue Will help to debug.print sqltext so you can see what is going to be executed and debug errors. Numeric datatypes don't need single quotes, but string values do.

Comment: Ok i will try it out. Thanks for now!

Comment: I think i got a little closer to the solution this is what i changed: I removed the If-Statement with the Counter vaiable completely! I added ```TempVars("F_ID") = txtF_SNr.Value``` to the form Load Event. And changed the where-part of my sql to this: ```Where " & txtStatus.Value & " <> Status AND [F_ID] = '" & Me.txtF_SNr.Value & "' ```

Comment: ...These changes i made sloved the problem! The Insert statement now only copies the old values for the record i changed to the new table. Thanks again for your help Lord Peter!

Comment: Glad you got it working! Don't forget to include some error handling (Google) and always make use of debug.print when you are building SQL statements "on the fly" - very helpful to see what is happening when something doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: Got It! Thank you!!